# Finding multiple instances of a regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a function which parses a string using regex to find short tags. It finds the first one, but none afterwards. What must I change?

```
$str = blah blah [img]inner1[/img] blah [img]inner2[/img]

function img_short($str)
{
    preg_match('/\[\bimg\b\](.*?)\[\/\bimg\b\]/', $str, $match);

    if ($match) {
        $out = $match;
    } else {
        $out = $str;
    }
    return $out;
}
```

My output is an array containing just the first regex grab

```
["[img]inner1[/img]", "inner1"]
```

Comment: use `preg_match_all` to do a global match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`preg_match()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) finds only the first occurrence. If you want to find **all** occurrences then you have to use [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php).

```
$str = 'blah blah [img]inner1[/img] blah [img]inner2[/img]';
$match = array();
preg_match_all('/\[\bimg\b\](.*?)\[\/\bimg\b\]/', $str, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($match);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [img]inner1[/img]
            [1] => inner1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => [img]inner2[/img]
            [1] => inner2
        )
)
```

**UPDATE:**

As @pguardiario remarked, the `\b` are not needed. They don't add value but only make the regex complicated. Here comes the simplified regex:

```
preg_match_all('#\[img\](.*?)\[/img\]#', $str, $match, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

I also changed the regex delimiter to `#` to have less characters to escape (`/` from `/img`).

Comment: those `\b`'s are worthless, they don't do anything at all.

Comment: That's right. I didn't analyze the regex, the question was about making it match all the occurrences, I focused on that. I updated now the answer with the simplified regex.

Comment: That's better but changing the delimiter doesn't help, it just makes it harder to read.